# How to use cards in material design with animation

Tags: android

am new to material design and I want to use cards like the ones used in inbox for my list view.

Please any help will do for me

Answer (score 0):

For having a ListView inside a card like layout, just like **Google Inbox**, here's a way to do so,

Create a drawable named **layout_bg.xml**, inside **res/drawable**,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
<stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
<corners android:radius="2dip"/>
<padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Now in your activity or fragment layout have your ListView embedded like this,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:elevation="2dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And voila, you have your Inbox styled card layout which contains your ListView.